# Passing value to module param in a static module

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have module param name "debug" in a module and the module is part of kernel image(uImage).

Is it possible to pass a value to this module param(debug) through kernel command line?

If different modules will have the same module parameter name then how I can pass the module param value to the desired module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard practice is to pass `module.parameter[=value]`.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. I have added module.parameter=value in the u-boot source for kernel command line arguments.